# First iOS app, where do all those downloads come from?

Tags: app-store

I published my first iOS app two days ago and it's been downloaded more than 500 times. I am responsible for about 20% of those and I am really confused about the rest. I've browsed the apps featured by Apple and mine wasn't in there. I've tried various keywords and my app was naturally not in the first pages. So where are those people seeing my app?

Comment: True randomness. Luck. Law of large numbers.

Comment: It's better to have too much downloads than too less ;)

Comment: Sure! I'm just puzzled. I guess all I can do is see if it continues at this pace or not.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be surprised about the countries the downloads are coming from. Often you might be at the top of a list in an App Store you don't visit.